Are all matrices equipped by definition with a matrix-vector product?
I am trying to be as precise as possible with the definitions for a numerical mathematics code that I am developing. This is a very synthetic summary of what I understand so far:
I understand that a matrix is "simply" an indexed set of numbers which we can use to represent linear maps, which is a much more abstract concept (but also others, like graphs). Similarly, I also understand that a tuple is just an ordered set of numbers that can be used to represent a vector in a vector space which, again, is a much more abstract concept.
My question is regarding the well-known matrix-vector product (or should I say matrix-tuple?):
Are all matrices inherently equipped with a matrix-vector product, or does this product require the context of a linear map between vector spaces?
In other words, are the "number gymnastics" independent of the more abstract concepts? Can we apply the matrix-tuple product to other things that do not represent linear maps or vectors?
Also, if matrices are equipped with such a product by default, does that promote them to some sort of algebraic structure?
I am asking because I would like to program the matrix-vector product in the right place of the code (i.e.: either inside a matrix class or a linear map class). I am somewhat familiar with some set-theoretic stuff and algebraic structures, in case answers go in that direction.
Thanks!

Hi @underflow,
I build a hierarchy of more or less abstract spaces based on set theory, implemented via OOP in C++ ('set' -> 'VectorSpace' -> etc)
As it is now, LinearMap inherits from map, which represents a mapping between two set* objects. LinearMap contains a matrix* object.  matrix is a base object for other, more specialized matrices (like Topelitz matrices, or others) and I specialize the product there.
If the matrix object is equipped with such an operation, does it become an algebraic structure? Or not necessarily?
Now that I write it, it seems not, right? :?

Yeah, I feel that calling this an algebraic structure may be kind of a twist... Mostly because defining the carrier set is somewhat tricky, isn't it? I think I am going to implement this matrix-vector (or maybe better, matrix-tuple) as just some kind of data structure, and that's it. Thanks for the discussion! It helped me see things clearer. :-)

I don't understand this question. What does it mean to say a matrix is "inherently equipped" with something or not? A matrix is just a bunch of numbers, we can decide what we want to do with them... if a monkey did all your matrix multiplications for you, you might also say it's inherently equipped with a monkey :)
To be slightly less facetious, you could look in Python for example, at the distinction between a numpy array (just numbers arranged into an array) and a numpy matrix (where multiplication is understood to be matrix multiplication.)

You will find that if you trace such ontological dependencies long enough, that what you get a net that has cycles and worse. To get a hierarchy of concepts one has to cut the net to get a spanning tree. How this is done is to a large degree arbitrary. (This does not even touch meta problems such as bootstrapping the logical foundations of mathematics via language theory, where the elements are finite sequences of symbols, without discussing that the idea of "element" is already set theory and "string" or "finite sequence" needs the advanced concept of integers as indices. This circle is of course not a new idea, just perplexing from the outside.)
To stay with the current domain, a matrix space, or a space of linear maps, are also vector spaces. But if you want to encode the vector space via tuples (which also form a vector space), you need a basis, or better said, any such encoding is a (dual) basis. Apart from the idea of a collection of vectors, a basis is also a pair of maps from the vector space to the coordinate space and back. This might be the preferred view if you want to disentangle the idea of a vector that is stored in computer memory.
To test ideas, think of the semi-trivial example class of Lie algebras of matrix groups. The tangent space at the identity then also consists of matrices, but the space does not have their full dimension, e.g., $so(n)$ has dimension $n(n-1)/2$. There is no canonical basis of one-nonzero-element matrices. A natural idea is to construct the basis from a set of algebraic generators. Etc.
One start of an idea for a class hierarchy goes as follows:

You have the class of abstract vector spaces.
Then there is a class of basis maps (containing also the dual map) that have their vector space as class parameter. They connect the however represented elements of the vector space with pairs of basis reference and coordinate tuple.
Similarly a linear map is encoded as triple of basis references for domain and range and a matrix.
When combining a linear map with a vector, one can compare the inner basis references and if they match perform the matrix-tuple product, otherwise a basis change has to performed first. Etc.

One could reduce the number of classes by observing that a vector is also a linear map from the scalar field into the vector space.
While theoretically basis maps are also linear maps, it would lead to circles to try to encode them as such.
